# Adding a "fake drive" to Windows Explorer

Tags: .net, windows-explorer, windows-explorer-integration

An application I use, [Mozy Backup](http://www.mozy.com), adds its own "drive" to Windows Explorer that I can browse and view all the files I've backed up. Windows knows it's not a physical drive - it's shows up under "Other" if my drive list is divided by type.

**How is a "drive" like this registered with explorer?** I'd like to do this with a current .NET application I'm developing, but I can't find any explanation about how it's done. Also, I can't seem to find any documentation about making my application "browsable", meaning that it presents a similar interface that a user can browse folders and files.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[Example of Mozy drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRX7e.gif)

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948505/how-to-mimic-a-drive-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not registered with explorer.  It is an operating system registration.  What you do is write a device driver for windows that gets installed on the local system and looks to windows like a disk drive device.  Instead of interfacing with some hardware (a physical device) your driver interfaces with something virtual (however, windows does not need to know this, it looks like a regular disk drive to windows).

You can find out more about writing device drivers here:

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/foundation/default.mspx

and here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809956.aspx

Comment: Hmmm - that appears to be way out of my class, but it's interesting to know how Windows does it. I suppose Windows doesn't care that it's not a physical disk, just like it doesn't know that "CloneDrive" isn't a real DVD drive, since it looks and acts like it is. Thanks for the links - I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction, if only so I can realize that it's beyond my skillset... :)

Comment: You welcome.  I've not looked, but there might be some open source projects that expose the functionality you want -- it might be worth it to dig a little and see if there is something "almost" doing what you need that has already been written.

Comment: The client application already allows users to "Browse" the contents, and I thought Explorer integration like this would be a nice feature for users. Since what they have now works, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

You are out - sorry. Not possible with a .NET application IIRC - this is driver level work, which means C++. What you basicalyl do is provide a proper driver for that, which the operating system then can connect to.

What you CAN do is expose stuff on a website supportin Web-DAV (which you can do in ASP.NET ergo .NET) and then the user can connect this via explorer (which supports connecting to a WebDAV data container).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Namespace Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

They are a pain and time-consuming to develop and get right, so you might want to take a look at [EZNamespaceExtensions.Net](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm) which eases things a lot.