# How to mimic a drive in Windows

Tags: windows-explorer

I recently had a look at the Google Data API. Its looking good.

What I want to do is create a "G Drive" Type application. This will basically come up as a drive in explorer with its own icon. From there you will be able to drag and drop operations to and from Google Docs, and create folders. Yes I've heard of Gladinet and Memeo, but both are not great solutions. I've decided to build one from the ground up, and release it as open source, once its in Alpha.

Anyways to get started I need some advise.

Clearly I need a way to mimic a drive in explorer. Is it possible to create some kind of virtual drive then have its contents list from an XML file, rather than a folder on the HDD?

So if the XML file (for example) contained a collection of  elements, would it be possible to have these elements (with some work) show up in an explorer window for the drive. Almost like changing the data source for the explorer view from file system to contents of a file?

Hack or not, elegant or messy, has anyone found some way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/) project may be what you're looking for

Comment: I've had a look around the site, it seems like this is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a drive look into [creating a namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx) which is how the [Google Drive works](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/gmail.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference: virtual drives can be created using our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) product, which is a supported, documented and maintained solution.